# How to fill the custom fields of users from the front-end form?

Tags: users, custom-field

how can i fill custom fields from the front-end form ?

https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using the `fields[customFieldHandle]` syntax.

For example, here's how you'd populate `location` and `bio` custom fields.

```
<label for="location">Location</label>
<input type="text" id="location" name="fields[location]" value="{{ currentUser.location }}">

<label for="bio">Bio</label>
<textarea id="bio" name="fields[bio]">{{ currentUser.bio }}</textarea>
```